# Change the caption color in a table generated with js

Tags: javascript

I created a table in javascript with this code :

```
var table = document.createElement('table')
table.style.verticalAlign = "top";
table.align = 'center';
table.createCaption().innerHTML ='Employee List'
table.caption.backgroundColor ="grey"
var row = table.insertRow(0); 
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.id = 'employee_off'
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); 
cell2.id = 'employee_on' 
document.body.appendChild(table)
employee_listManager();
```

The problem is, even if the caption background is grey, hen i load the page, the background is white...

I m searching on the internet how to change his color, but i found nothing for the caption...

Should i create a span or a td only for the caption?

thx

Comment: “Even if the caption background is grey… the background is white”. This does not make sense to me. Why do you expect the caption background to be gray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `syle` property to use css style, something like this.

```
 table.caption.style.backgroundColor ="grey";
 //--------------^
```

instead of

```
table.caption.backgroundColor ="grey";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7FKKk/)